# Disable button after 1 click

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make simple grid for game. I am very novice to c# and programming. Could someone help me how I can restrict clicks of buttons. I want to create only one player in my grid so after 1 click I want to restrict user to creating more player. I need your expert help.

```
protected void SetClicks()
    {
        foreach ( Control c in this.panel1.Controls)
        {
            if ( c is Button )
            {
                Button who = c as Button;
                who.Click += new EventHandler(WhoClicked);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void MakeButtons()
    {
        rowNum = UpDownRow.Text;
        int nr = Int16.Parse(rowNum);    
        colNum = UpDownColumn.Text;
        int nc = Int16.Parse(colNum);
        int btnHeight = panel1.Height / Int16.Parse(rowNum);
        int btnWidth = panel1.Width / Int16.Parse(colNum);
        for (int row = 0; row < nr; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < nc; column++)
            {
                Button btnNew = new Button();
                btnNew.Name = "btn_" + column + "_" + row;
                btnNew.Height = btnHeight-5;
                btnNew.Width = btnWidth-5;
                btnNew.Font = new Font("Arial", 20);
               // btnNew.Text = theSymbol;
                btnNew.Image = Properties.Resources.backg;

                btnNew.Visible = true;
               // int CenterPoint = panel1.Width / 3;
                btnNew.Location = new Point(10 + (column* btnNew.Width), 10 + (row* btnNew.Height));

                //Controls.Add(btnNew);
                panel1.Controls.Add(btnNew);

            }
        }
    }



private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            picSymbol = Properties.Resources.Player;

            button2.Enabled = false;
           // want some help here

            MessageBox.Show("Too Many Player", "Player number exceed",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem did you debug it ?

Comment: This should work exactly as expected.

Comment: That's fine as it is, except that the message box will show after the first click. Remove the messagebox

Comment: i am able to disable the button but it keeps on creating player on my grids. I don't know where I messed up.

Comment: Does your grid have many buttons? If so, are all the buttons hooked to the same event? It should be, but you'll also have to disable all the buttons. Not just the one you clicked

Comment: yes, I have many buttons. I want to restrict to player only.

Comment: So, all your buttons should hook to the same click event, and in the event you'll set your player and disable all the buttons.

Comment: In order to preserve your time may I point out a eventual design flaw ? If you are only allowed to create one player and you need at least one player to play the game doesn't this means there always has to be exact one player ? Which then means this player can be created at the start of the game without the user having to click any button at all ?

Comment: @PaulWeiland you are right, but I need this function for my project. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want that:

Suppose the `button2` starts as enabled.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    picSymbol = Properties.Resources.Player;


    //Will only run if button is disabled, which is after the first player creation.

        button2.Enabled = false;
        btn.Text = "Game Disabled";


}
```

As mentioned in the comments, maybe your grid has many buttons and all hooked with the same event.

In this case, you would use the `sender`, which is the button that fired the event.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    picSymbol = Properties.Resources.Player;
    Button btn = sender as Button;

    //Will only run if button is disabled, which is after the first player creation.
    if (!btn.Enabled){
        MessageBox.Show("Too Many Player", "Player number exceed",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        //or

        btn.Text = "Game Disabled";
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Enabled = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Buttons don't fire click events if they are disabled. This code will only disable the clicked button (still creating a player). If all buttons run this event, you still haven't solved the problem

Comment: Oh, he wants to disable every button if one of them is clicked? Or after x number of buttons are clicked?

Comment: That was kind of dumb of me. I forgot about this, sorry XD

Comment: Exactly bixarrio, I am having same condition.

Comment: @Phiter, could you see my all code that I have added now in question then probably you could point me where I messed up, I am still getting same.

Answer (score 2):

You must choose between disabling the button or showing a message box when the user clicks the enabled button for the second time. Disabled buttons do not respond to user activity so you cannot respond to the second click.

Most WinForms users are quite used to disabled controls - what you *could* do is disable the button and change its `Text` to "Game full" so the user understands why it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If the only buttons on your form are in the grid, you can do this;

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    picSymbol = Properties.Resources.Player;

    foreach (var control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is Button)
        {
            control.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not been tested, but it should do

**EDIT**

Based on your updated question, I've added the event binding at button creation and defined the event handler;

```
protected void MakeButtons()
{
    rowNum = UpDownRow.Text;
    int nr = Int16.Parse(rowNum);    
    colNum = UpDownColumn.Text;
    int nc = Int16.Parse(colNum);
    int btnHeight = panel1.Height / Int16.Parse(rowNum);
    int btnWidth = panel1.Width / Int16.Parse(colNum);
    for (int row = 0; row < nr; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < nc; column++)
        {
            Button btnNew = new Button();
            btnNew.Name = "btn_" + column + "_" + row;
            btnNew.Height = btnHeight-5;
            btnNew.Width = btnWidth-5;
            btnNew.Font = new Font("Arial", 20);
           // btnNew.Text = theSymbol;
            btnNew.Image = Properties.Resources.backg;

            btnNew.Visible = true;
           // int CenterPoint = panel1.Width / 3;
            btnNew.Location = new Point(10 + (column* btnNew.Width), 10 + (row* btnNew.Height));

            // hook this button to a click event
            btnNew.Click += new EventHandler(WhoClicked);

            //Controls.Add(btnNew);
            panel1.Controls.Add(btnNew);

        }
    }
}

private void WhoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    picSymbol = Properties.Resources.Player;

    foreach (var control in this.panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (control is Button)
        {
            control.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ bixarrio I have added my other code in question, can you have a look and suggest me where I messed up, I am still not being able to restrict my player button. 
Thanks

Comment: The code above should be in your `WhoClicked` event handler. Also update `this.Controls` (in my code) to `this.panel1.Controls`